# Convert PSObjects (or PS Command) to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, powershell

I am trying to create a web API that will convert the output of a PowerShell command to JSON. Is there a library that can do this or convert a PSObject to JSON?

The PSObject properties changes depending on the command that generates it. I tried passing the PSObject to "ConvertTo-Json", but I got extra object information.

PowerShell command:

```
Get-Process | Select -Property Handles,ProcessName | ConvertTo-Json
```

The output after JsonConvert.SerializeObject():

```
"{\"CliXml\":\"<Objs Version=\\\"1.1.0.1\\\" xmlns=\\\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04\\\">\\r\\n  <Obj RefId=\\\"0\\\">\\r\\n<TN RefId=\\\"0\\\">\\r\\n <T>System.String</T>\\r\\n      <T>System.Object</T>\\r\\n    </TN>\\r\\n    <ToString>[_x000D__x000A_    {_x000D__x000A_\\\"Handles\\\":163,_x000D__x000A_\\\"ProcessName\\\":\\\"AppleMobileDeviceService\\\"_x000D__x000A_},_x000D__x000A_    {_x000D__x000A_\\\"Handles\\\":  972,_x000D__x000A_\\\"ProcessName\\\":\\\"CcmExec\\\"_x000D__x000A_},_x000D__x000A_{_x000D__x000A_\\\"Handles\\\":  1838,_x000D__x000A_\\\"ProcessName\\\":\\\"ccSvcHst\\\"_x000D__x000A_}"
```

PowerShell command to BeginInvoke.

PowerShell command:

```
Get-Process | Select -Property Handles,ProcessName
```

The output after JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PSObj):

```
"[{\"CliXml\":\"<Objs Version=\\\"1.1.0.1\\\" xmlns=\\\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04\\\">\\r\\n  <Obj RefId=\\\"0\\\">\\r\\n    <TN RefId=\\\"0\\\">\\r\\n      <T>Selected.System.Diagnostics.Process</T>\\r\\n      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>\\r\\n      <T>System.Object</T>\\r\\n    </TN>\\r\\n    <ToString>@{Handles=163; ProcessName=AppleMobileDeviceService}</ToString>\\r\\n    <Obj RefId=\\\"1\\\">\\r\\n      <TNRef RefId=\\\"0\\\" />\\r\\n      <MS>\\r\\n        <I32 N=\\\"Handles\\\">163</I32>\\r\\n        <S N=\\\"ProcessName\\\">AppleMobileDeviceService</S></Objs>\"}}]
```

Comment: `ConvertTo-JSON` sounds like exactly what you're after... what were the extra properties?  If you want to remove properties you can use select-object to specify just those properties you're after before converting to json.

Comment: That didn't work updated the post with the data.

Comment: Convert-Json is NOT a good solution in my opinion because it converts enums to their ordinal value.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494409/powershell-retain-the-text-of-all-enum-properties-with-convertto-json

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with using a third-party library, then [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) has the `JsonConvert` class. It's fairly straightforward to use: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj)` will return a string containing the JSON.

I find this to be a bit easier than trying to programmatically call PowerShell from C# code.

If there are extra properties that you would like to omit, then JsonConvert allows you to implement an [IContractResolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) to specify which properties you would like.

It ends up looking like so:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver() });
```

And the ContractResolver looks like so:

```
public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        properties = properties.Where(p => p.PropertyName != "OmittedProperty").ToList();
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Of course, you can make the condition for the properties anything you like.

Comment: Keep in mind that while inspecting strings in Visual Studio, it will add leading and trailing quotation marks, as well as escape quotation marks and backslashes. So " and \ will appear as \" and \\ respectively. Is that the issue you noticed with the output?

Comment: I'll check the code you posted. Thank you for helping out. It's not just in VS. I outputed the data to a Console Window and then also outputed data to a web-browser and saw the same issue.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get around this? I've been running into same problem. The cause lays with the Serializer of the PSObject that always serializes the properties of the PSObject to CliXML. I've tried enumerating over the properties (while adding them to a collection) to some success, but some cmdlets (get-childitem and get-command for instance) raise a runspaceexception when you call try to read the properties from the object.

Comment: Note that "ConvertTo-Json" is not a standalone module. It's part of Powershell. It's an open issue to break it out into a separate library. See: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3995

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for a solution to this, the built in JSON converter (ConvertTo-Json) from Powershell can be utilised as such:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace PowerJson
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the Powershell instance, and adds command to be executed
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddCommand("Get-Process");
            Collection<PSObject> _ps_results = ps.Invoke();

            // Create a JSON Context Object
            JsonObject.ConvertToJsonContext _json_context = new JsonObject.ConvertToJsonContext(maxDepth: 12, enumsAsStrings: false, compressOutput: false);

            // Converts the PSObject into JSON
            string json_result = JsonObject.ConvertToJson(_ps_results, _json_context);

            // Outputs the result to console
            Console.WriteLine(json_result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Try it out.

```
if (item.TypeNames.FirstOrDefault() == "System.String")
{
    return item.BaseObject.ToString();
}
else
{
    var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
        { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var objMembers = typeof(object).GetMembers();
    var ignoreMembers = new List<string>();

    ignoreMembers.AddRange(
        item.Members.Where(
            i => i.TypeNameOfValue.StartsWith("Deserialized.")).Select(i => i.Name).ToList());

    ignoreMembers.AddRange(objMembers.Select(i => i.Name));

    var filteredMembers =
        item.Members.Where(
            i => ignoreMembers.All(
                ig => ig.ToLower() != i.Name.ToLower())).ToList();

    foreach (var mem in filteredMembers)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(mem.Name))
        {
            dict.Add(mem.Name, "");
        }
        dict[mem.Name] = mem.Value;
    }

    try
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, settings);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: This is a code snippet. In which context is it supposed to work?

Comment: Sorry, missed this comment.  It takes the item, which is the returned item from powershell process.  Then iterates over those to serialize the response to json.  I have since beefed up this code a bit, but it still serves it purpose.