# Powershell - Retain the text of all Enum properties with ConvertTo-Json

Tags: json, powershell, enums

For "*Get-Msoldomain*" powershell command-let I get the below output (*lets call it Output#1*) where Name, Status and Authentication are the property names and below are their respective values.

```
Name                    Status   Authentication

myemail.onmicrosoft.com Verified Managed
```

When I use the command with "ConvertTo-Json" like below

```
GetMsolDomain |ConvertTo-Json
```

I get the below output (*lets call it Output#2*) in Json Format.

```
{
    "ExtensionData":  {

                      },
    "Authentication":  0,
    "Capabilities":  5,
    "IsDefault":  true,
    "IsInitial":  true,
    "Name":  "myemail.onmicrosoft.com",
    "RootDomain":  null,
    "Status":  1,
    "VerificationMethod":  1
}
```

However, the problem is, that if you notice the **Status** property in both the outputs, it's different. Same happens for **VerificationMethod** property. Without using the ConvertTo-JSon Powershell gives the Text, and with using ConvertTo-Json it gives the integer.

When I give the below command

```
get-msoldomain |Select-object @{Name='Status';Expression={"$($_.Status)"}}|ConvertTo-json
```

I get the output as

```
{
    "Status":  "Verified"
}
```

However, I want something so that I don't have to specify any specific property name for it to be converted , the way I am specifying above as

```
Select-object @{Name='Status';Expression={"$($_.Status)"}}
```

This line is transforming only the **Status** Property and not the **VerificationMethod** property because that is what I am providing as input .

Question: Is there something generic that I can give to the "**ConvertTo-Json**" commandlet, so that It returns ***ALL*** the Enum properties as Texts and not Integers, without explicitly naming them, so that I get something like below as the output:

```
{
    "ExtensionData":  {

                      },
    "Authentication":  0,
    "Capabilities":  5,
    "IsDefault":  true,
    "IsInitial":  true,
    "Name":  "myemail.onmicrosoft.com",
    "RootDomain":  null,
    "Status":  "Verified",
    "VerificationMethod":  "DnsRecord"
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, if you don't mind to take a little trip :) you can convert it to CSV which will force the string output, then re-convert it back from CSV to PS Object, then finally back to Json.

Like this:

```
Get-MsolDomain | ConvertTo-Csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Json
```

- If you need to keep the original Types instead of converting it all to string see mklement0 helpful answer...

Comment: A simple and pragmatic solution, but (efficiency aside) it comes with a big caveat: _All_ property values are invariably converted to strings, which is generally undesirable.

Answer (score 11):

**[PowerShell *Core*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** (PowerShell **versions 6 and above**) offers a simple solution via [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6)'s **`-EnumsAsStrings` switch**.

```sh
GetMsolDomain | ConvertTo-Json -EnumsAsStrings  # PS *Core* (v6+) only
```

---

Unfortunately, this switch **isn't supported in *Windows PowerShell***.

[Avshalom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44495061/45375) provides a quick workaround that comes with a big caveat, however: *All* property values are invariably converted to *strings* in the process, which is generally undesirable (e.g., the `Authentication` property's *numeric* value of `0` would turn into *string* `'0'`).

Here's a more generic **workaround based on a filter function** that recursively introspects the input objects and outputs ordered hashtables that reflect the input properties with enumeration values converted to strings and all other values passed through, which you can then pass to `ConvertTo-Json`:

```sh
Filter ConvertTo-EnumsAsStrings ([int] $Depth = 2, [int] $CurrDepth = 0) {
  if ($_ -is [enum]) { # enum value -> convert to symbolic name as string
    $_.ToString() 
  } elseif ($null -eq $_ -or $_.GetType().IsPrimitive -or $_ -is [string] -or $_ -is [decimal] -or $_ -is [datetime] -or $_ -is [datetimeoffset]) {
    $_
  } elseif ($_ -is [Collections.IEnumerable] -and $_ -isnot [Collections.IDictionary]) { # enumerable (other than a dictionary)
    , ($_ | ConvertTo-EnumsAsStrings -Depth $Depth -CurrDepth ($CurrDepth+1))
  } else { # non-primitive type or dictionary (hashtable) -> recurse on properties / entries
    if ($CurrDepth -gt $Depth) { # depth exceeded -> return .ToString() representation
      Write-Warning "Recursion depth $Depth exceeded - reverting to .ToString() representations."
      "$_"
    } else {
      $oht = [ordered] @{}
      foreach ($prop in $(if ($_ -is [Collections.IDictionary]) { $_.GetEnumerator() } else { $_.psobject.properties })) {
        if ($prop.Value -is [Collections.IEnumerable] -and $prop.Value -isnot [Collections.IDictionary] -and $prop.Value -isnot [string]) {
          $oht[$prop.Name] = @($prop.Value | ConvertTo-EnumsAsStrings -Depth $Depth -CurrDepth ($CurrDepth+1))
        } else {      
          $oht[$prop.Name] = $prop.Value | ConvertTo-EnumsAsStrings -Depth $Depth -CurrDepth ($CurrDepth+1)
        }
      }
      $oht
    }
  }
}
```

**Caveat**: As with `ConvertTo-Json`, the recursion depth (`-Depth`) is limited to `2` by default, to prevent infinite recursion / excessively large output (as you would get with types such as `[System.IO.FileInfo]` via `Get-ChildItem`, for instance). Similarly, values that exceed the implied or specified depth are represented by their `.ToString()` value. Use `-Depth` explicitly to control the recursion depth.

Example call:

```sh
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ p1 = [platformId]::Unix; p2 = 'hi'; p3 = 1; p4 = $true } | 
      ConvertTo-EnumsAsStrings -Depth 2 |
        ConvertTo-Json

{
  "p1": "Unix",   # Enum value [platformId]::Unix represented as string.
  "p2": "hi",     # Other types of values were left as-is.
  "p3": 1,
  "p4": true
}
```

<sup>Note: `-Depth 2` isn't necessary here, given that `2` is the default value (and given that the input has depth `0`), but it is shown here as a reminder that you may want to control it explicitly.</sup>

---

If you want to implement **custom representations for *additional* types**, such as `[datetime]`, `[datetimoffset]` (using the ISO 8601-compatible .NET [round-trip date-time string format, `o`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier), as PowerShell (Core) v6+ *automatically* does), as well as `[timespan]`, `[version]`, `[guid]` and `[ipaddress]`, see [Brett's helpful variation of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68355976/45375).

Comment: This is a far better answer than the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I needed to serialize pwsh objects to JSON, and was not able to use the `-EnumsAsStrings` parameter of `ConvertTo-Json`, as my code is running on psv5. As I encountered infinite loops while using @mklement0's code <sup>Editor's note: since fixed.</sup>, I rewrote it. My revised code also deals with the serialization of some other types such as dates, serializing them into the ISO 8601 format, which is generally the accepted way to represent dates in JSON. Feel free to use this, and let me know if you encounter any issues.

```
Filter ConvertTo-EnumsAsStrings ([int] $Depth = 10, [int] $CurrDepth = 0) {

  if ($CurrDepth -gt $Depth) {
    Write-Error "Recursion exceeded depth limit of $Depth"
    return $null
  }

  Switch ($_) {
    { $_ -is [enum] -or $_ -is [version] -or $_ -is [IPAddress] -or $_ -is [Guid] } {
      $_.ToString()
    }
    { $_ -is [datetimeoffset] } {
      $_.UtcDateTime.ToString('o')
    }
    { $_ -is [datetime] } {
      $_.ToUniversalTime().ToString('o')
    }
    { $_ -is [timespan] } {
      $_.TotalSeconds
    }
    { $null -eq $_ -or $_.GetType().IsPrimitive -or $_ -is [string] -or $_ -is [decimal] } {
      $_
    }
    { $_ -is [hashtable] } {
      $ht = [ordered]@{}
      $_.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        $ht[$_.Key] = ($_.Value | ConvertTo-EnumsAsStrings -Depth $Depth -CurrDepth ($CurrDepth + 1))
      }
      if ($ht.Keys.Count) {
        $ht
      }
    }
    { $_ -is [pscustomobject] } {
      $ht = [ordered]@{}
      $_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty') {
          Switch ($_) {
            { $_.Value -is [array] -and $_.Value.Count -eq 0 } {
              $ht[$_.Name] = @()
            }
            { $_.Value -is [hashtable] -and $_.Value.Keys.Count -eq 0 } {
              $ht[$_.Name] = @{}
            }
            Default {
              $ht[$_.Name] = ($_.Value | ConvertTo-EnumsAsStrings -Depth $Depth -CurrDepth ($CurrDepth + 1))
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if ($ht.Keys.Count) {
        $ht
      }
    }
    Default {
      Write-Error "Type not supported: $($_.GetType().ToString())"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Some nice improvements. As for `[datetime]` and `[datetimeoffset]`: Unless you don't mind losing time-zone information, I suggest not using UTC. PowerShell (Core) v6+, which also uses the `o` format, uses the local time, if applicable (e.g., `2021-07-12T23:37:13.803887-04:00`).

Comment: @mklement0 At least in my testing, PSv5 also supports this. But good point - I may revise this, as the traditional advice of storing UTC times in databases might get me into trouble if timezone rules ever change. Storing with the offset may be more future-proof.