# Powershell - Retain Complex objects with ConvertTo-Json

Tags: json, powershell, csv, enums

Powershell command-let *ConvertTo-Json* has the following limitations
1) It returns Enum values as Integers instead of their text
2) It doesn't return the date in a readable format

For point #1 see below, Status and VerificationMethod Properties

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Msoldomain | ConvertTo-Json


{
    "ExtensionData":  {

                      },
    "Authentication":  0,
    "Capabilities":  5,
    "IsDefault":  true,
    "IsInitial":  true,
    "Name":  "myemail.onmicrosoft.com",
    "RootDomain":  null,
    "Status":  1,
    "VerificationMethod":  1
}
```

To handle this, I changed my command as below

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Msoldomain | ConvertTo-Csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Json

{
    "ExtensionData":  "System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject",
    "Authentication":  "Managed",
    "Capabilities":  "Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline",
    "IsDefault":  "True",
    "IsInitial":  "True",
    "Name":  "curtisjmspartnerhotmail.onmicrosoft.com",
    "RootDomain":  "",
    "Status":  "Verified",
    "VerificationMethod":  "DnsRecord"
}
```

Now you see, that the enums are being returned with their text values above (Status and VerificationMethod) instead of their integer values.

However, There are a few limitations with this approach:

> 1) ConvertTo-Csv doesn't retain the Arrays or Complex Objects, and
>   outputs them as their Class Names (Watch the ExtensionData Properties
>   in both the outputs). In the second output, we tend to lose the data,
>   and just get the className
>   **System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject** as a string
>
> 2) Both ConvertTo-Csv and ConvertFrom-Csv are not the script-level
>   commandlets, but they are command-level commandlets, which means that
>   we can't use them at the end of the script , but they will have to be
>   used with the individual commands like I am doing above. WHEREAS,
>   ConvertTo-Json need not be applied at the commmandLevel, but just
>   applied once for the script output.

My question is:

1) How do I still use the convertTo-Json, so that all my enum properties are returned with their texts and not integers, and ALSO the Complex Objects or Arrays are not lost? In the approach I have used, the complex objects are getting lost

2) Also, it should be generic enough so that It can be applied at the end of the script, and not at the command level

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "script-level" and "command-level" cmdlets; it sounds like you're applying a concept to PowerShell inappropriately. If you have any reference for such concepts please supply a link.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of your earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44494409/5771128

Comment: Hi, It exactly is not a duplicate as it is asking how to retain the complex objects with convertTo-Json. In my previous question, I had asked how to retain the Enum values as texts instead of integers.

Comment: I tried cahvers answer below. No Luck, however I then tried this approach and it seems to have worked well.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024450/491196

Answer (score 2):

`ConvertTo-Json` and `ConvertTo-Csv` are both forms of serializing objects in some sort of text representation and both are useful in different use cases.

`ConvertTo-Csv` is perhaps best used for 2-dimensional data that can be expressed in a table such as a spreadsheet. Hence it is awkward to try to convert "complex" objects, i.e. those with properties that contain other structured data, into a simple table. In such cases PowerShell represents such data as the full name of the data type.

`ConvertTo-Json` is capable of serializing more complicated objects, since the format allows for nested arrays/data structures, e.g. the **ExtensionData** property in your example. Note that you may need to use the `-Depth` parameter to ensure that deeply nested data is serialized correctly.

So the problem really comes down to how the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet serializes enums, which can be demonstrated with:

```
[PS]> (Get-Date).DayOfWeek
Tuesday

[PS]> (Get-Date).DayOfWeek.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType   
-------- -------- ----      --------   
True     True     DayOfWeek System.Enum

[PS]> Get-Date | Select DayOfWeek | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "DayOfWeek":  2
}
```

So before you convert to JSON you need to ensure that the **DayOfWeek** property (in this example) or **Status** and **VerificationMethod** properties (from your example) are converted to their string equivalents first.

You can do this using an expression with `Select-Object` to convert the data as it passes down the pipe. Note that you *do* need to include *all* the properties that you want included in the final JSON:

```
[PS]> Get-Date |
  Select DateTime,@{Label="DayOfWeek";Expression={$_.DayOfWeek.ToString()}} |
  ConvertTo-Json
{
    "DateTime":  "13 June 2017 10:33:51",
    "DayOfWeek":  "Tuesday"
}
```

So in your case you'd need something like this:

```
[PS]> Get-Msoldomain |
  Select-Object ExtensionData,IsDefault,IsInitial,Name,RootDomain `
    ,{Label="Authentication";Expression={$_.Authentication.ToString()}} `
    ,{Label="Capabilities";Expression={$_.Capabilities.ToString()}} `
    ,{Label="Status";Expression={$_.Status.ToString()}} `
    ,{Label="VerificationMethod";Expression={$_.VerificationMethod.ToString()}} |
  ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Right, However I do not want to list the specific properties like you have done here using Select-Object. Is there something generic, that would do this automatically to these properties, so that I don't have to bother about making projections about properties. Something that can be put between my command-let and convertTo-Json and does it for all properties?

Comment: You could pull out all the properties for the object, check whether the are enums and build up a new object which has those enums converted to strings... Will post this as a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

@puneet, following your comment on my other answer, here is an example of how you might build up a new object, based on an existing one, with the **Enum** types converted to strings.

The idea is to create a new "empty" object, then loop through all the properties of the original object and add them to the new one, but if any of the original properties are Enums, then those are converted to strings.

```
$data = [PSCustomObject]@{}

(Get-Date).PSObject.Properties | Select Name,Value | Foreach-Object {
  if($_.Value.GetType().BaseType.FullName -eq "System.Enum"){
    $data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value.ToString()
  }
  else {
    $data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value
  }
}

$data | ConvertTo-Json
```

You may want to finesse this a little for your own application, but hopefully the idea behind it is clear. Definitely check to see that all the properties are being treated correctly in the JSON output.

Comment: The way you loop through "(Get-Date).PSObject.Properties", I cannot do that for every command in my script. My script will consist of several command-lets. I need a generic way, so that it works for the script as a whole and not applicable at the command-let.

Comment: In other words, I would like something applicable on the script output, rather than at the individual command level

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean, and I think this is branching off to another question. I've been focussing on the narrow question of how to serialize Enums as strings when converting to JSON.

Comment: You might need ask a new questions with a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) script that shows this more clearly, as it sounds like you may need help with creating a function to do this conversion repeatedly and/or work out how to write output from a script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

to keep enum,array and date when converting psObject to json, you can use newtonsoft. a sample here https://github.com/chavers/powershell-newtonsoft using Nerdy Mishka powershell module.

```
$obj = New-Object pscustomobject -Property @{Enum = (Get-DAte).DayOfWeek; int = 2; string = "du text"; array = @("un", "deux", "trois"); obj= @{enum = (Get-DAte).DayOfWeek; int = 2; string = "du text"; array = @("un", "deux", "trois")}}
Import-Module Fmg-PrettyJson
$settings = Get-NewtonsoftJsonSettings
$enumconv = "Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter"
$e = New-Object $enumconv
$settings.Converters.Add($e)
Set-NewtonsoftJsonSettings $settings
$obj | ConvertTo-NewtonsoftJson
```

return:

```
{
  "array": [
    "un",
    "deux",
    "trois"
  ],
  "enum": "Thursday",
  "int": 2,
  "obj": {
    "enum": "Thursday",
    "array": [
      "un",
      "deux",
      "trois"
    ],
    "int": 2,
    "string": "du text"
  },
  "string": "du text"
}
```

Comment: I tried this by importing the above module.  When I ran it against the above command 'Get-Msoldomain | ConvertTo-NewtonsoftJson' it returned an empty object {}.  Any idea what might be happening?